# Suspend problem associated with ethernet on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: suspend, ethernet

I have an Asus Vivobook s200 with Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on it. I have the following problem. After booting the laptop the ethernet works and if i click suspend it works normally. Then when I wake the laptop and i log in everything works fine except for the ethernet, which seems to be completely dead (if I go to network preferences it's always saying "cable disconnected"). Another anomaly is that after this first time suspend doesn't work anymore, instead I get some error messages (which appear for a brief period of time) and then the system goes back to the login screen.
I've managed to grab a screen of the error messages
[image: screenshot]

As far is I've understood these errors are related to the ethernet, so the ethernet not working and the impossibility to suspend are probably related.
I'm a linux newbie so I need help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution to that worked for me is disable networking and disconnect the ethernet.
After a while reconnect the ethernet and enable networking . 
This oftens works without much trouble.
[image: Disable and enable networking from this panel.]
Cheers.